# Aggregate query for IBM Cloudant which is basically couchDB

Tags: node.js, couchdb, cloudant, node-red

I am a contributor at http://airpollution.online/ which is open environment web platform built open source having IBM Cloudant as it's Database service.

Platform's architecture is such way that we need to fetch latest data of each air pollution measurement devices from a collection. As far as my experience go with MongoDB, I have wrote aggregate query to fetch each devices' latest data as per epoch time key in each and every document available in respective collection.

Sample Aggregate query is :

```
db.collection("hourly_analysis").aggregate([
{
    $sort: {
        "time": -1,
        "Id": -1
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        "Id": 1,
        "data": 1,
        "_id": 0
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        "_id": "$Id",
        "data": {
            "$last": "$$ROOT"
        }
    }
}
```

If someone has idea/suggestions about how can I write design documents in IBM Cloudant, Please help me! Thanks!
P.S. We still have to make backend open source for this project. (may take some time)

Comment: Can you give a general overview of what you're trying to do?  What does the data look like, and what question do you need to answer from that data?  I'm not sure from this MongoDB example what you have in CouchDB and what you're aiming to retrieve.

Comment: Hello @LornaMitchell, what I am trying to do is there are GBs of data coming from different devices. so I need to pick every device's latest data. every document has "deviceId" and "time" in epoch time. as an example you can try this open api which gives latest data of https://openenvironment.p.mashape.com/all/public/devices use header "X-Mashape-Key" : "AznHXmVhecmsh2eRvaAX42EKCmj3p1lRLpzjsnks0zMETqI4Mg"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CouchDB/Cloudant this is usually better done as a view than an ad-hoc query.  It's a tricky one but try this:
 - a map step that emits the device ID and timestamp as two parts of a composite key, plus the device reading as the value
 - a reduce step that looks for the largest timestamp and returns *both* the biggest (most recent) timestamp and the reading that goes with it (both values are needed because when rereducing, we need to know the timestamp so we can compare them)
 - the view with group_level set to 1 will give you the newest reading for each device.

In most cases in Cloudant you can use the built-in reduce functions but here you want a function of a key.

(The way that I solved this problem previously was to copy incoming data into a "newest readings" store as well as writing it to a database in the normal way.  This makes it very quick to access if you only ever want the newest reading.)